# Principle of inference

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I was reading Russel's "Human Knowledge". He started with principle of inference. I'm not getting a hang of it though.(I'm just curious reader, not a philosopher in any means).

So a "easily conceivable" description will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Could you quote the relevant passage?

Comment: I'm at my office right now, so i dont have the book. But it talks about "scepticism". How a partial "scepticism" leads to logical contradiction.

Comment: I don't have that piece with me either. Do edit the question with the passage once you are home; the info you've provided so far is not enough to provide an answer ("principle of inference" doesn't mean anything concrete).